# Missing results in export when running scrapy spider with multiple start_urls

Tags: scrapy, export-to-csv, splash-screen, missing-data

I am running a scrapy spider to export some football data and using the scrapy splash plugin.

For development I am running the spider against cached results, so as not to hit the website too much. The strange thing is, that I am consistently missing some items in the export when running the spider with multiple start_urls. The number of missing Items differ slightly each time.

However, when I comment out all but one start_urls and run the spider for each one separately, I get all the results. I am not sure if this is a bug with scrapy or if I am missing something about scrapy here, as this is my first project with the framework.

Here is my caching configuration:

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = [403]
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

These are my start_urls:

```
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2017',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2018',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2019',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2020',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/2-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L2/plus/?saison_id=2017',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/2-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L2/plus/?saison_id=2018',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/2-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L2/plus/?saison_id=2019',
    'https://www.transfermarkt.de/2-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L2/plus/?saison_id=2020'
]
```

I have a standard setup with an export pipeline and my spider yielding splash requests multiple times for each relevant url on the page from a parse method. Each parse method fills the same item passed via cb_kwargs or creates a new one with data from the passed item.

Please let me know if further code from my project, like the spider, pipelines or item loaders might be relevant to the issue and I will edit my question here.

Comment: Hard to tell this way, anything in logs?

Comment: @Tarun I am not seeing any errors in my logs unfortunately. I only noticed when there was clearly less data in the export file. I am thinking it might have something to do with the ansychronus nature of scrapy. I could post some log output from sinlge url run vs multi url run to pastebin, if that might help to get an idea.